# Test Class returning error

Tags: trigger, class

Can anyone substantiate why this is?

```
    Opportunity o2 = new Opportunity();
    o2.Name = 'DSGTestClassRecord Opportunity 2';
    o2.StageName = 'New';
    o2.CLoseDate = Date.today();
    insert o2;

    Opportunity OppRec1 = [select Id From Opportunity Where Name = 'DSGTestClassRecord Opportunity 2'];
    OppRec1.StageName = 'Closed Won';
    OppRec1.Sub_Stage__c = 'Paid';
    OppRec1.Opportunity_Discount_Approved__c = true;

    update OppRec1;
```

In this class code, the OppRec1 SELECT statement is returning that no rows are found.  What?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) instead of using name= 'DSGTestClassRecord Opportunity 2' do Id = : o2.Id;

```
Opportunity OppRec1 = [select Id From Opportunity Where id=: o2.Id];
```

2) If you want to verify the name is the one you inserted

```
System.assertEquals('DSGTestClassRecord Opportunity 2', o2.name);
```

Comment: Interesting.  I had misunderstood that the search (by name) was important to the particular test being done, but it is not.  Thanks!

Comment: I am sure you might have tried looking up, but just incase the reference slipped out,check this doc : http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests